# Using Git from the server to push to github

Tags: git, github

For this project I'm working on, I'm developing live on the server (not my decision) and I'd like to, if possible, push from the server to GitHub, is that possible? I can't seem to find any resources, maybe I'm just looking for the wrong thing!

If it's not possible are there any workarounds?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you on an existing repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should just need to add your github repository as a remote in your repository, and then push to that remote.

All the commands you need are here: http://help.github.com/remotes/